# how to configure WSGISocketPrefix

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am getting a permissions issue when running django in daemon mode.  Reading here https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets I think the solution is to configure the `WSGISocketPrefix`

The problem is that `/var/run/wsgi` is no where to be found on my centos server.

The closes thing I can find is:  `/etc/httpd/run/httpd.pid`

How can I find where `wsgi` is installed?

Or what other value can I set the WSGISocketPrefix equal to?

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS, Django11.1, Python 3.6.1, and mod_wsgi-4.5.15 it works for me as follows:

Apache was showing the following error:

- 503 Service Unavailable

Apache error log showed the following:

- [wsgi:error] [pid 5411] (2)No such file or directory: [client 1.2.3.4:12345] mod_wsgi (pid=5411): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'mywsgi' on '/var/run/apache2/wsgi.5403.0.1.sock' as user with uid=123.

Note that I'm running WSGI as a different user than the default www-data. This is changed with 'user' from WSGIDaemonProcess.

**Solution:**

- At the bottom of **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**, add:

**WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/apache2/wsgi**

- After restarting Apache, I can ls -la and see the lock files under **/var/run/apache2**:

apache2.pid

wsgi.5017.0.1.sock

**Sources:**

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGISocketPrefix.html?highlight=WSGISocketPrefix%20
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationIssues.wiki#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

Comment: That doesn't make sense. According to the error message you set it to the exact same thing that it was trying to use. More likely your problem was different and was a transient issue caused by having done a graceful restart of Apache and a HTTP client was using a keep alive connection. The subsequent requests on the same client connection tried to connect  to a daemon process that no longer existed because it was restarted. Would suggest try unsetting it again.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the original question. But in any case, what I described resolved the problem I was facing.